# two in parameters c

Tags: c, arrays, loops, pwm

Im working on enabling multiple PWM at once, and i dont wanna copy paste the code 6 times but im having trouble to enable 6 different PWMs, the code that works is :

```
    void pwmPinChoices(void){

    pwm_channel_disable(PWM, PWM_CHANNEL_7);
    pwm_pin6_instance.ul_prescaler = PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;
    pwm_pin6_instance.ul_period = 100;
    pwm_pin6_instance.ul_duty = 50;
    pwm_pin6_instance.channel = PWM_CHANNEL_7;
    pwm_channel_init(PWM, &pwm_pin6_instance);
    pio_set_peripheral(PIOC, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PC24B_PWML7);
    pwm_channel_enable(PWM, PWM_CHANNEL_7);
}
```

I want to be able to change pwm_pinx_instance and pwm_channel_x, i tried using arrays but it does not work..

The code i tried is:

```
    void pwmChoices(void){
    char ChlArr = [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7];
    char PinArr = [34, 36, 6, 7, 8, 9];

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
    pwm_channel_disable(PWM, PWM_CHANNEL_ChlArr[i]);
    pwm_PinArr[i]_instance.ul_prescaler = PWM_CMR_CPRE_CLKA;
    pwm_PinArr[i]_instance.ul_period = 100;
    pwm_PinArr[i]_instance.ul_duty = 50;
    pwm_PinArr[i]_instance.channel = PWM_CHANNEL_ChlArr[i];
    pwm_channel_init(PWM, &pwm_PinArr[i]_instance);
    pio_set_peripheral(PIOC, PIO_PERIPH_B, PIO_PC24B_PWMLChlArr[i]);
    pwm_channel_enable(PWM, PWM_CHANNEL_ChlArr[i]);
}
```

But with this code i get alot of errors that the functions are undeclared..

Comment: At least `pwm_PinArr[i]_instance` has to be `pwm_PinArr_instance[i]`, where pwm_PinArr_instance is an array of function poiters. Otherwise you have to read something about templates.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access constants (like PWM_CHANNEL_7) via array values in runtime. You can't do that. Constants in C are resolved at compile time.

Comment: Show the definition of `pwm_pin6_instance`

Answer (score 1):

if your function look like this

```
void pwm_pin6_instance ( void )
```

Then you can declare an array

```
void (*pwm_PinArr_instance[7]) (void);
```

And init it: (ampersand is optional)

```
pwm_PinArr_instance[0] = &pwm_pin0_instance;
pwm_PinArr_instance[1] = &pwm_pin1_instance;
pwm_PinArr_instance[2] = &pwm_pin2_instance;
pwm_PinArr_instance[3] = &pwm_pin3_instance;
pwm_PinArr_instance[4] = &pwm_pin4_instance;
pwm_PinArr_instance[5] = &pwm_pin5_instance;
pwm_PinArr_instance[6] = &pwm_pin6_instance;
```

Then you can use the array

```
 pwm_channel_init(PWM, pwm_PinArr_instance[i]);
```

**EDIT**

Looking deeply in your code I think you have to learn something about array.
I guess you are thinking that the translation of `PWM_CHANNEL_ChlArr[i]` will be, for `i=0`, `PWM_CHANNEL_0`.

Array values are not substituite to variable name at compile time.

**Take time to study arrays and to learn how to use them.**

Answer (score 1):

It's

```
char ChlArr[] = {0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7}
char PinArr[] = {34, 36, 6, 7, 8, 9};
```

and not

```
char ChlArr = [0, 1, 4, 5, 6, 7];
char PinArr = [34, 36, 6, 7, 8, 9];
```